# Asp.net mvc, validation error msg

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

How does asp.net mvc figures out validation error message for particular field?

I got class with 3 fields where one of them is with type DateTime. When i post form and no data are provided for DateTime field and it is marked as Required, validation summary can't figure out field name and shows "A value is required" instead of expected "The electronic version arrival date is required". Other fields got correct msg.

Can't understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709293/how-to-override-the-a-value-is-required-while-validating-a-datetime-format-in/709395#709395) myself.